# Cross platform, multi-syntax highlighting editor

Tags: open-source, syntax, editor

Is there an editor that is:

1. Available for at least windows and linux
2. Highlights multiple syntaxes in the same document. (Ala Dreamweaver)
3. Tabbed interface

All the editors I tried highlighted by file extension only which isn't fine grained enough.
At the very least it needs to distinguish scripting from html, css and javascript in the same document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is emacs. You can do pretty much anything you want with that editor. There is a 'nxhtml-mode' which you can use to edit javascript, php, html,ruby, jsp,css, whatever on the same file. If you're still at university, the best advice I can give you is to start learning how to use emacs. It will change your life, really.

Answer (score 4):

[Scite!](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html)

Answer (score 2):

- Eclipse (very good, but heavy)
- vim (doesnt have tabs, but aprt from that very lightweight and very good)
- emacs (only heard about it that is is very good, but it has a steap learning curve)

hop it helps

Comment: vim/gvim since v7 does have tabs

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans.

I've only tried it with HTML av Javascript for two languages in the same file though.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [jedit](http://www.jedit.org/). Just need a java runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Handling syntax highliting and completion for multi-language files is something the NetBeans people have been working on and has been available [for javascript](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaScript#section-JavaScript-EmbeddedCompletion) since 6.1. I got the impression from [JavaPosse#214](http://javaposse.com/index.php?post_id=398366) that this has seen further work in 6.5.

I don't Netbeans myself (my primary tools are Emacs and Eclipse), but It might be worth a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

[SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html) FTW!!! Doesn't even need an installation! A portable single exe.